# 2d matrix using linked list of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

> /**
>       * Initializes the 2D Matrix (in place of a constructor)
>        * Rows and Columns must both be greater than zero.
>        * @param rows integer specifying the height of the matrix, must be > 0.
>        * @param cols integer specifying the width of the matrix must be > 0.
>        * @return boolean, true if inputs were acceptable, false otherwise.
>        */

```
public boolean init(int rows, int cols) 
{
    matrix = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
    if(this.rows < 0 || this.cols < 0)
        return false;

    if(this.rows > 0 && this.cols > 0)
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)   
            matrix.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                matrix.get(cols).add(j);
        return true;


}
```

I am trying to initialize this matrix using linked list of linked list, but i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `{` and `}`. It's a good rule for beginner to always put curly brackets for your `if` and `for`.

In your example, even if the second `for` is indented, it won't be part of your first loop.

Also your loop is not correct, it should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        list.add(0);
    }
    matrix.add(list);
}
```